# Generate internal and external docs from single source using Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to find information on Sphinx's ability to tag certain bits of documentation as 'internal' and build it like `sphinx-build -b -include internal source output` where the `-include` flag would contain a series of tags to include in the output.

That would allow me to generate 2 versions (or more) of my docs while keeping it single-source.

Example:

```
.. audience::internal

Page title
============

This whole page will be available only in the internal docs.
```

or

```
Page title
============

This whole page will be available in the internal and external docs. 

.. audience::internal

That p will only be available in the internal docs.

This p will be available in the internal and external docs.
```

Is there such a mechanism? If not, would that be difficult to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifconfig` is one way to do this indeed, but after asking around, it seems that there is a better mechanism:

[`.. only::` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-only)

Use it to tag something:

```
.. only:: internal

   Page title
   ============

   This whole page will be available only in the internal docs.
```

Then you can run a build with the `-t` option to publish everything tagged with `internal` (or whatever you used)

```
sphinx-build -t internal -b html source output
```

Answer (score 2):

The Sphinx extension [ifconfig](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/ifconfig.html) might do what you want, although you would have to indent content.